# How do I write a jQuery function that iterates consecutively numbered selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the tooltipster plugin to fire the names of over 60 buildings on a map. Each location is a div and the tooltip shows on hover over the respective element. I've also got a list of the locations at the bottom of the map. I've worked out how to get the plugin to fire on mouseover of each respective list item and launch that corresponding tooltip.

What I want to know is how to write this function in a way that will make it so I don't have to write it some 60 odd times with variations in the numbering. This is what I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tooltip').tooltipster();
$('#link-1').mouseover(function() {
$('#apDiv1').tooltipster('show');
$('#link-1').mouseout(function() {
$('#apDiv1').tooltipster('hide');

$('#link-2').mouseover(function() {
$('#apDiv2').tooltipster('show');
$('#link-2').mouseout(function() {
$('#apDiv2').tooltipster('hide');           
});
});
});
});
});
```

Everything is numbered consecutively. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Adding an example of how the divs with the tooltips are coded:

```
<div class="number tooltip" title="Message about location 1" id="apDiv1">1</div>

  <div class="number tooltip" title="Message about location 2" id="apDiv2">2</div>
```

Comment: Also, suggest clearing your concepts about selectors (class, id) etc e.g. http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I understand the difference between classes and ids...and if you link the function to a common class name, which all of these divs have, btw, they all fire at once so...yeah.

Comment: Okay, got it. There are solutions in that case like assigning an attribute like `data-for` in your triggering element, read it and use it to isolate the required element (to apply the function to) using class and attribute selector. Or using some manipulation like `children()`, `find()`, `next()` etc from the triggering element using `$(this)`. Hope your task is already completed.

Answer (score 2):

Give the same class name instead of assigning to different IDs and then use tool-tip function for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
   $('.link').mouseover(function() {
   $('.appDiv').tooltipster('show');
   $('.link').mouseout(function() {
   $('.appDiv').tooltipster('hide');
});
```

Comment: That fires all 60+ tooltips at once when you hover one of the list items.

Comment: no it would not. anyway if you are facing problem use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault)